# Web service deployment without error

Tags: web-services, deployment, weblogic

I am trying to deploy a web service that I wrote, to my local weblogic server.

I have deployed other web services here, but never had any issues.

When I add the following line of code to my app, is when I get the error.

**Line Of Code**:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "--------------------SessionEJB")
```

**Error**:

```
[09:17:44 AM] Deploying 2 profiles...
[09:17:44 AM] Wrote EJB Module to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\MyApp\------EJB\deploy\MyAppEJB.jar
[09:17:44 AM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\MyApp\deploy\MyApp.ear
[09:17:44 AM] Redeploying Application...
[09:17:45 AM] [Deployer:149192]Operation 'deploy' on application 'MyApp' is in progress on 'DefaultServer'
[09:17:45 AM] [Deployer:149193]Operation 'deploy' on application 'MyApp' has failed on 'DefaultServer'
[09:17:46 AM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
[09:17:46 AM] Remote deployment failed
```

Without that line of code, it deploys just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployed the EAR manually, instead of trying to deploy to weblogic server from Jdeveloper.

Weblogic is telling me my errors.